# "Moving" # meters (over ground) from LatLonA to LatLonB (WGS84)

Tags: c#, algorithm, gis

I need a function in C# to do the following: move 50 meters from gps-point A in the direction of gps-point B and calculate the GPS-coordinates for that point.

For instance I've got two coordinates:

```
LatLon LatLonA = new LatLon(51.83966, 5.04631); // Latitude 51.83966, Longitude 5.04631
LatLon LatLonB = new LatLon(51.84172, 5.01961); // Latitude 51.84172, Longitude 5.01961
```

What I would like is a function like this:

```
function LatLon MoveTowards(LatLon A, LatLon B, double MetersOverGround) 
{
    //code here
}
```

That function would return the coordinate which is x meters away from A in the direction of B.

Comment: I've used the Haversine formula to calculate distances between points before, but I'm just not sure how to wrap up an algorithm that works the way I'm asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Earth is not a sphere, nor even an ellipse.  The best you can hope for without purchasing a commercial library would be an approximation (which for most people is good enough).

You could start by looking into the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), and [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) will be of great help.

Or if you want a commercial library, I have used [ProLat](http://www.effectiveobjects.com/eoprolatdll4-specs.html) with great success

Comment: I've used the Haversine formula to calculate distances between points before. An approximation would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want. Just use `Math.Atan2` to obtain the bearing of your A-to-B vector and obtain the `bearing` parameter.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the end-point from a given source at a given range (meters) and bearing (degrees).
    /// This methods uses simple geometry equations to calculate the end-point.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Point of origin</param>
    /// <param name="range">Range in meters</param>
    /// <param name="bearing">Bearing in degrees</param>
    /// <returns>End-point from the source given the desired range and bearing.</returns>
    public static PointLatLng CalculateDerivedPosition(PointLatLng source, double range, double bearing)
    {
        const double DEGREES_TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180;
        const double EARTH_RADIUS_M = 6371000;
        double latA = source.Lat * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS;
        double lonA = source.Lng * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS;
        double angularDistance = range / EARTH_RADIUS_M;
        double trueCourse = bearing * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS;

        double lat = Math.Asin(
            Math.Sin(latA) * Math.Cos(angularDistance) +
            Math.Cos(latA) * Math.Sin(angularDistance) * Math.Cos(trueCourse));

        double dlon = Math.Atan2(
            Math.Sin(trueCourse) * Math.Sin(angularDistance) * Math.Cos(latA),
            Math.Cos(angularDistance) - Math.Sin(latA) * Math.Sin(lat));

        double lon = ((lonA + dlon + Math.PI) % (Math.PI * 2)) - Math.PI;

        return new PointLatLng(
            lat / DEGREES_TO_RADIANS,
            lon / DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
    }
```